# Cordova CLI - what hooks are executed for each command

Tags: cordova-3

I'm just starting to work with Cordova.  I've been developing some hooks to support project version control.  I've been trying to understand which hooks get executed for each given CLI command.  I discovered that during a cordova platform add, that the after_prepare hooks are being executed before the after_platform_add hooks are called.  This makes no sense to me and I have been unable to find out which hooks are executed, and in what order, for each of the CLI commands.  A table would be really nice here.

Thanks,